# How to check for a value whether it is set or not

Tags: php

For an SQL query designed to handle missing values, I am using following test for having a value:

```
if ($true<>'') {
    $strSet.="true='$true',";
}
```

If true is TRUE i.e. 1, then it passes this test. However, if true is FALSE i.e. 0, it is currently failing.

Is this the correct behavior for <>''?  Should I be testing in some other way?

Comment: You might want to try using `!=` or `!==` rather than `<>`.

Comment: why not do an `IF` statement of `if ($true == 1){...} else{...}`, unless there are some other values you're actually comparing? Why overcomplicate the logic?

Comment: It is going into a query that has multiple fields that may or may not have values so am trying to keep it as simple as possible.  Also, this is actually part of an IOS call to a server API so it is happening in JSON and a bit hard to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that:

- if `$true` is TRUE then it will show 1 ( the value of `$true` here is 1 ).
- if `$true` is FALSE then it will show nothing because it's considered as `''` (empty).

You can change your code to be like this, `isset()` is the function you need:

```
if(isset($true)){
   $strSet.="true='$true',";
}
```

This actually worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The test for an empty string is very different from looking for a 1 or 0. If you know the values could be either of those results, then write your if accordingly.

```
if ($true != 0) {
```

You could also use the php "empty" function:

```
if (!empty($true)) {
```

Or this should also work for an even simpler method:

```
if ($true) {
```

Edited to fix the variable name.

Comment: To be clear I am testing for the absence of a value for this variable, not trying to distinguish between them.

Comment: Either of those last two examples should do that for you.